# Problem for register service worker vue.js

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I tried to turn my application into weight but I have the following errors.

```
registerServiceWorker.js:26 Error during service worker registration: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://test/page/') with script ('https://test/service-worker.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed
```

Service worker

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
  registrationOptions: { scope: '.', type: 'module' },
  ready() {
    console.log('Service worker is active.')
  },
  registered() {
    console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
  },
  cached() {
    console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
  },
  updatefound() {
    console.log('New content is downloading.')
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
  },
  offline() {
    console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
  },
  error(error) {
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
  }
})
```

vue.config.js

```
pwa: {
    // configure the workbox plugin
    name: 'Test',
    themeColor: '#d06161',
    msTileColor: '#000000',
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',
    iconPaths: {
      favicon32: 'img/icons/favicon-32x32.png',
      favicon16: 'img/icons/favicon-16x16.png',
      appleTouchIcon: 'img/icons/icon-152x152.png',
      maskIcon: 'img/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg',
      msTileImage: 'img/icons/icon-144x144.png',
    },
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
      swSrc: 'src/registerServiceWorker.js',

      swDest: 'src/service-worker.js',
      // skipWaiting: true,
      importWorkboxFrom: 'disabled',
      importScripts: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js',

      // ...other Workbox options...
      exclude: [/\.htaccess$/],
    },
  },
```

manifest and index.html

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "short_name": "Test",
  "theme_color": "#172b4d",
  "icons": [
    {
        "src": "/img/icons/icon-192x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/img/icons/icon-256x256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/img/icons/icon-384x384.png",
        "sizes": "384x384",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/img/icons/icon-512x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
    }
],
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#fff",
  "start_url": "/"
}

 <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
```

So I searched everywhere for information, I was told that all this is correct but I do not know how to proceed
Do you have another solution on how to proceed with this weight application?
Is there a solution to this error or did I do something wrong?
I just want it to be fixed and a popup to appear so that I can install it on the homescreen but there are still problems when registering the service worker

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you've your own service-worker. The mode `workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest'` you used is for people who have their own service worker implementation. I think you should use `workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW'`.
The file `'src/registerServiceWorker.js'` you thought is your service worker is not. It's to help you do stuff like register your service worker. For more details, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/register-service-worker

`Vue-cli` constructs the service worker based on google `workbox`, so visit the next link for more details about when to use a specific mode : https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/

Now, when you change the mode, the option `swSrc` of `workboxOptions` is where the build process will put your generated service worker file. By default it's your build destination folder (if you don't provide a value to `swSrc`, it would be e.g: `dist/` directory). So make sure the registration of the service worker made by the script in `'src/registerServiceWorker.js'` locates the generated service worker according to the value you provide to `swSrc`.